# SharePoint 2010 can't find or use ListData.svc

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Can anyone lead me in the direction on how to access/enabled/use the ListData.svc in SharePoint 2010? When we try to access it via our web browser, we get a 404 error. Is there a service we need to enabled, or install a component, please help?

Comment: If it is a 404 that looks like it was browser-produced, it may be the way you're requesting the contents. If the error is server-produced (e.g. standard Sharepoint or IIS error), you may be in a hosted environment with ADO.NET missing.

Answer (score 3):

One way for this to happen is if a list doesn't actually work (in the browser it errors when you try to open it). Another symptom would be that Sharepoint designer doesn't show anything for lists and libraries.

I got this by following along a learning book. If there is a list that relies on a feature or something that is no longer installed this might happen.

One answer is to delete the offending list(s) using powershell;

```
$w = Get-SPWeb "http://localhost"<br />
$w.Lists.Delete([System.Guid]$w.Lists["MyListName"].ID)
```